# R - interesting issue with either data frame or global variable

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Take a look at this code. I am trying to make code that starts with an empty data frame with only IDs and dynamically adds data. For example, let's say it starts with

```
  ID
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

And then I make a call

```
addPair(1,"a",4); #sets the value of column "a" at row 1 to be the value 4
```

it would become

```
ID    a
1  1  4
2  2  NA
3  3  NA
```

Take a look at this code below. The **desired** final `total` variable is:

```
ID   a  
1  1 4  
2  2 NA
3  3 NA
```

But at the end, `total` is just

```
  ID
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Here is the code. Why is `total` not keeping what it adds? At the end of the method, total is correct, but then after the method, total is back to just the `IDs`. Here is the code and below is the output.

```
# rm(list=ls())  # that code _should_ always be commented out

#get all the IDs
IDs = c("1","2","3")
N = length(IDs)

#the big data frame
total <- data.frame("ID"=IDs)

addPair = function(i,name,val) {
    total[,toString(name)] = rep(NA,N)
    total[,toString(name)][i] = val
    print("end")
    print(total)
}

addPair(1,"a",4)
print("after call")
print(total)
```

Here is the output:

```
[1] "end"
  ID  a
1  1  4
2  2 NA
3  3 NA
> print("after call")
[1] "after call"
> print(total)
  ID
1  1
2  2
3  3
```

Why does `total` lose that column `a` after the method is over?

Comment: Because in R, what happens in Vegas stays in Vegas (unless you tell someone about it). Now replace 'Vegas' with 'function'. Everything that happens in your function happens in an environment created by the function that is then discarded when you exit the function.

Comment: `addPair` just takes a one-column dataframe, manipulates it and shows what manipulation happened; nothing is being saved. A quick fix is using `<<-` instead of `=` to change and save `total` in your `.GlobalEnv`.

Comment: what might perhaps be more surprising to you is that when your function runs the line `total[,toString(name)] = rep(NA,N)` it first actually _copies_ `total` into the local environment in the function, and then modifies _that_.

Comment: Don't listen to @alexis_laz. The use of `<<-` is the siren call of persons who want R to be like SAS or BASIC. Avoid the blandishments of a quick fix and learn to use `$<-` as assignment to a new column in your target dataframe. Or learn to use `transform` which it appears you are attempting to reinvent.

Comment: @DWin: I agree with the "careful with `<<-`" but I don't think it is of no use at all. If you know _where_ you have _what_, you can make it work as expected. In fact, I might say it's better to see what problems `<<-` can produce and dig into the world of environments and scoping, than just use `R`'s "classy" functions like `transform` (or `subset`) that have warning even in their `help()` pages. I love the homeric comment, though! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
transform(total, a = {b=rep(NA,N); b[1] <- 4;b })
  ID  a
1  1  4
2  2 NA
3  3 NA
```

Returns desired object, however it does not change `total` unless you assign the value to that name.

```
 addPair <- function(df,item,name, val) transform(
                         df, name={t=rep(NA,nrow(df)); t[item]=val;t} )
 addPair(total, 1,"a",4)
  ID name
1  1    4
2  2   NA
3  3   NA

> total <- addPair(total, 1,"a",4)
> total
  ID name
1  1    4
2  2   NA
3  3   NA
```

Unfortunately as when using `with`, `transform` is more designed for console use than programming. It's not totally safe for coding use.